# How to correctly change Binding via DataTrigger in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

If I change the Binding in Entry.Text using "Style Trigger", the second field is overwritten with the information from the first Binding. In other words, Person.Name is overwritten by Person.Surname

**Can you reproduce this behaviour and tell me how can I improve it?**

*Below is the complete code*

**Style definition**

```
<Style TargetType="Entry" x:Key="MyStyle">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Entry" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference mySwitch}, Path=IsToggled}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Text">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Binding Path="Surname" Mode="TwoWay" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Entry" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference mySwitch}, Path=IsToggled}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Text">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Binding Path="Name" Mode="TwoWay" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**Target Entry and Switch:**

```
<Label Text="Actual Person.Name" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
<Label  Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
<Label Text="Actual Person.Surname" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
<Label  Text="{Binding Path=Surname}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
<Label Text="Person.Name / Person.Surname" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" />
<Switch x:Name="mySwitch" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
<Label Text="Change Name/Surname" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" />
<Entry  Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" />
```

**Code Behind:**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private Person p = new Person { Name = "Joe", Surname = "Doe" };
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = p;
    }
}
```

**Source:**

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _surname = "Doe";
    public string Surname
    {
        get => _surname;
        set
        {
            if (value != _surname)
            {
                _surname = value;
                Raise();
            }
        }
    }
    private string _name = "Joe";
    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            if (value != _name)
            {
                _name = value;
                Raise();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void Raise([CallerMemberName] string name = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

**---------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**It seems to me that the problem is with behavior when switching Triggers, because this phenomenon does not occur if I perform a similar test from the code level.**

**The following example works as expected:**

**Test Class**

```
public class Test
{
    public void Run1()
    {
        Person p = new Person { Name = "Joe", Surname = "Doe" };
        Bindable bindable = new Bindable();
        Binding bindingToName = new Binding("Name");
        Binding bindingToSurname = new Binding("Surname");

        bindable.BindingContext = p;

        bindable.SetBinding(Bindable.TextProperty, bindingToName);
        bindable.SetBinding(Bindable.TextProperty, bindingToSurname);
        bindable.SetBinding(Bindable.TextProperty, bindingToName);
        bindable.SetBinding(Bindable.TextProperty, bindingToSurname);
        bindable.SetBinding(Bindable.TextProperty, bindingToName);
        bindable.SetBinding(Bindable.TextProperty, bindingToSurname);
    }
}
```

**Custom BindableObject**

```
public class Bindable : BindableObject
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Text", typeof(string), typeof(Bindable), "", propertyChanged: MyPropertyChanged);       
    private static void MyPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Property changed from '{oldValue}' to {newValue}");
    }
}
```

**Source**

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _surname = "Doe";
    public string Surname
    {
        get => _surname;
        set
        {
            if (value != _surname)
            {
                _surname = value;
                Raise();
            }
        }
    }
    private string _name = "Joe";
    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            if (value != _name)
            {
                _name = value;
                Raise();
            }
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void Raise([CallerMemberName] string name = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

**Run Test**

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Test().Run1();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**Result (as expected)**

```
Property changed from '' to Joe
Property changed from 'Joe' to Doe
Property changed from 'Doe' to Joe
Property changed from 'Joe' to Doe
Property changed from 'Doe' to Joe
Property changed from 'Joe' to Doe
```

Comment: I have no idea why this is happening, but this problem occurs between Triggers. I struggle with this problem in many ways and I can not fix it, will you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The reason I think this is happening is that when your Person class has initialized the Data in Name an Surname is null and hence until the data is provided to them this weird behaviour will happen.

My suggestion to you would define the Name and Surname properties with a default value i.e. string.Empty which will help you avoid this something like this:

```
public class Person
{
   public string Name{get;set;} = string.Empty;
   public string Surname{get;set;} = string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: My source is completed with data before loading this page (it is completed in ViewModel before calling the page).
I connect the source like this: <Entry BindingContext = "{Binding Person}".

I do not think this is the cause, I assume the cause is null in Entry.Text between trigger1 and trigger2 (?) Have you checked if it works correctly for you?

Comment: See when you bind a property to the Widget what happens here is as soon as that widget is created the binding that is provided as data will become the value of that so what I think is as soon as you give it the binding it should take that value and push it to the Text property so your scenario of between triggers is sort of impossible only if you provide a default value(I hope i make sense)

Comment: Your statement is a bit too complicated for me, so I can not understand it, but it may be my weakness. :)

Comment: Just set a default value to your Name and Surname then see if it works or not and if not we can find some other solution for the same

Comment: Just in case, I added default values (but I'm sure the source is completed) and nothing changes. This is some bug in xamarin.forms in my opinion.  Change: public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _surname = "Doe";
        public string Surname
        {
            get => _surname;
            set
            {
                if (value != _surname)
                {
                    _surname = value;
                    Raise();
                }
            }
        } […]

Comment: Can you add the XAML for your Entry and the also on what basis are you updating the Binding i mean the boolean

Comment: I described more precisely what the problem is and I added all the essential elements of my solution.